# 2001 Hyundai Sonata System too lean

Tags: hyundai, sonata, p0171

I own a 2001 Hyundai Sonata. Check engine light is on, and I'm getting an error code P0171, Bank 1 System too lean.

I figured I'd start eliminating problems, so when I ran an ODB check, what I got was a lot of monitors were in Ready mode, except the following:

1. EVAP
2. O2S
3. CAT

I've driven around countless miles, but somehow I can't get these monitors in ready. The first thing I've started with was checking the O2 sensor. I can't figure out which O2 sensor I'm checking, and I don't know where Bank 1 is. I'm not sure if I pulled out the right sensor, but I think the sensor before the converter would be bank 1?

Images are provided: (This is a sensor that I haven't yet pulled out just yet)

[image]

This is the sensor I think that won't go in ready mode, but I'm not sure:

[image]

The above sensor was a sensor right below the sensor in the first picture, going into a pipe, I'm assuming the exhaust to the converter.

Is it possible you guys happen to know what 02s I need to check? Again, it shows the O2S not in Ready mode, and I've driven for a while and it still isn't on.

The error code is **P0171 Bank 1 System Too Lean**

Comment: Bank 1 usually refers to one side of an engine or the other on a V6, or if a 4-cyl, there is only one bank. Usually a code will read bank 1 sensor 1 (B1S1) for the before cat and bank 1 sensor 2 (B1S2) for after cat. Also, in order to get it into ready mode, you will most likely have to go through several heat/cool cycles.

Comment: @Paulster2 Alright, but when i run the scan using an ODB, it shows that a o2s isn't ready. Would you happen to know what sensor this is referring to?

Comment: It is just telling you both (assuming 4-cyl) O2 sensors are not ready. Until you go through several cycles, you won't know if one or the other is bad.

Comment: @paulster2 I've been through so many, and it still isn't showing in ready mode. However my Ho2s is in ready mode. the one I pulled out, is that an o2s or an Ho2s? if you can tell?

Comment: In a straight-N engine, Bank 1 is the only bank you get in OBD or OBDII - nothing is Bank 2. The O2 sensor upstream of the cat is O2 Sensor 1, the downstream one is Sensor 2. Sensor 2 in your case may never reach a "ready" condition, and the cat may never reach a "ready" condition, because your system is running too lean to feed the catalyst. Let's see about getting your lean condition fixed. Fuel pump, pressure regulator, injectors.

Comment: @TrippedStackers ... But, you may or may not be doing the cycles correctly. Every manufacturer has a little different "cycle". But for most, you need to ensure it is driven so *everything* is heated, then *everything* is cooled back down. Considering the catalyst is directly downstream of the exhaust port and that the O2 sensors themselves are heated, it will heat up. If the engine is running lean, the exhaust gas temps will actually be running *hotter* which means the cat itself will heat even faster. And, I hope you aren't trying to clear it each time you check, or you start all over again.

Answer (score 1):

Bank 1 on any engine is the bank that carries No 1 cylinder. Sensor1 is the first sensor from where the exhaust manifold bolts onto the engine/head. Some scans will show an 'N/A' on a four cylinder engine for Bank2. This means that the ECU is programmed for a four cylinder, but can be programmed for a 6 or 8 cylinder vee using differant software. Your vehicles ECU software monitors must all run to set all components to Ready, this is called a drive cycle. Your EVAP system is tested by a leakage test with a scanner, which will also check the systems purge valve and pressure sensor. Any system leaks can be found with a smoke test. The EVAP system needs the O2 sensor to be working correctly on a drive cycle to set the EVAP to Ready. The O2 sensor can be tested by a propane test. The Cat uses a second dedicated sensor after the Cat to monitor the Cat's performance, to pass the Cat to Ready. Correct testing of components in essential, anything else is a guess.